# how do I snap an extruded face to be level

Tags: extrude

[image]how do I raise the selected face and make it level with the side next to it, ctrl/shift comes close but its off slightly. I would like to not have any faces on the inside as well.

Comment: Try turning on merge vertices mode as well as vertex snap mode. the inside face on the side will have to be manually removed though.

Comment: snap to vertex with center turned on worked, vertex with closest enabled also worked but could be recreated it worked once. Thank you.